My Arduino code stops working when i try to manipulate the ports instead of using pinMode() and digitalWrite()
The uncommented code works perfectly fine, but as you can see i have commented all the port related lines which i think should do the equivalent as the uncommented ones, but when i uncomment those and comment the others the code just doesent do anything.
Im working with and LCD for an university assingment, my arduino is an Arduino Leonardo. The LCD controller is hd44780u by HITACHI. The function set_byte inverts the byte because my connections are inverted too (Arduino pin 0 connected to pin 7 of the LCD).
#define sbi(port, bit) (port) |= (1 << (bit))
#define cbi(port, bit) (port) &= ~(1 << (bit))

// Sets up all pin modes
void setup() {
  // TODO: cambiar esto y ponerlo con sbi por eficiencia
  //DDRD |= B11111111;  // Configura todos los pines de PORTD como salida
  //DDRB |= B00000111;  // Configura pines 8, 9, 10 como salida
  
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

// Defines all commands
#define DISPLAY_ON 0x0C
#define DISPLAY_OFF 0x08
#define CURSOR 0x0E
#define NO_CURSOR 0x0C
#define BLINK 0x0D
#define NO_BLINK 0x0C
#define SCROLL_R 0x18
#define SCROLL_L 0x1C
#define HOME 0x02
#define AUTOSCROLL 0x07
#define NO_AUTOSCROLL 0x06
#define CLEAR 0x01

// Writes the values in the pins
void set_byte(uint8_t in_byte){
  in_byte = (in_byte & 0xF0) >> 4 | (in_byte & 0x0F) << 4;
  in_byte = (in_byte & 0xCC) >> 2 | (in_byte & 0x33) << 2;
  in_byte = (in_byte & 0xAA) >> 1 | (in_byte & 0x55) << 1;
  for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
    digitalWrite(i, 0b00000001 & (in_byte >> i));
  }

  /*in_byte = (in_byte & 0xF0) >> 4 | (in_byte & 0x0F) << 4;
    in_byte = (in_byte & 0xCC) >> 2 | (in_byte & 0x33) << 2;
    in_byte = (in_byte & 0xAA) >> 1 | (in_byte & 0x55) << 1;
    PORTD = in_byte;*/
}

// Sends a command to the display
void send_command(uint8_t command){
  // Set RS and R/W
  //cbi(PORTB, 2);
  digitalWrite(10, 0);
  //cbi(PORTB, 1);
  digitalWrite(9, 0);

  // Set bit values
  set_byte(command);

  // Signal Enable
  //sbi(PORTB, 0);
  //cbi(PORTB, 0);
  digitalWrite(8, 1);
  digitalWrite(8, 0);

  //Uses a different delay based on the commands
  if(command == CLEAR || command == HOME)
    delay(2);
  else
    delayMicroseconds(50);
}

// Writes the introduced byte in the LCD 
void write(uint8_t in_char){
  // Set RS and R/W
  //sbi(PORTB, 2);
  //cbi(PORTB, 1);
  digitalWrite(10, 1);
  digitalWrite(9, 0);

  // Set bit values
  set_byte(in_char);

  // Signal Enable
  //sbi(PORTB, 0);
  //cbi(PORTB, 0);
  digitalWrite(8, 1);
  digitalWrite(8, 0);

  delayMicroseconds(50);
}

// Writes the introduced String into the LCD
void write_str(char* char_str){
  while(*char_str != 0){
    write(*char_str);
    char_str++;
  }
}

// Sets the cursor to a position between 0-60
void move_cursor(uint8_t position){
  // Puts cursor in starting position
  send_command(0x80);
  
  // Ignores non valid positions
  if(position < 0 || position > 80) return;

  // Writes the instruction position time
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < position; i++){
    set_byte(0b00010100);

    // Signal Enable
    //sbi(PORTB, 0);
    //cbi(PORTB, 0);
    digitalWrite(8, 1);
    digitalWrite(8, 0);
  
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
}

// Sends all initialization commands
void lcd_begin() {
  // Enviar "Function Set" tres veces para establecer modo 8 bits
  send_command(0x30);
  delay(10);
  send_command(0x30);
  delayMicroseconds(200);
  send_command(0x30);

  send_command(0x3C);
  send_command(DISPLAY_OFF);
  send_command(CLEAR);
  send_command(NO_AUTOSCROLL);
}     

I was expecting for it to work, because if im right it is equivalent.
void loop() {
  lcd_begin();
  send_command(DISPLAY_ON);

  for(uint8_t i = 65; i < 91; i++){
    write(i);
    delay(50);
  }

  delay(1000);
}

This piece of code for example, that prints the letters in the alphabet works perfectly fine with the pinMode()/digitalWrite() approach but does nothing manipulating ports.

Why do you think this should work? Uno and Leonardo don't use the same MCUs, so pin mapping isn't the same.

I watched an arduino doc that showed which pins are equivalent to the ports in a Leonardo and it said DDRD 0-7 and DDRB 8-13. Im not using Uno maping i guess https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/hacking/software/PortManipulation/

That link doesn't mention Leonardo, neither its MCU ATmega32u4.

Thats true my bad for not looking better. But can you give me solutions or are you going to just keep telling me that im wrong?

To initialize the pins 0-10 the code should be:
DDRD = 0b10011111;
DDRC = 0b01000000;
DDRE = 0b01000000;
DDRB = 0b01110000;

Arduino Leonardo Pinout
